# Getting error "Your JAVA_HOME is invalid" when building with Ionic, PATH and JAVA_HOME variables are set

Tags: java, android, cordova, ionic-framework

When trying to run the command `ionic cordova run android`, I end up with the following error:

```
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=C:\Android\android-sdk (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=undefined (DEPRECATED)
Failed to run "javac -version", make sure that you have a JDK version 8 installed.
You can get it from the following location:
https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html        

Your JAVA_HOME is invalid: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_271
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

        cordova.cmd build android exited with exit code 1.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

When I looked up other people who've had this error, it seems the issue was either they didn't have JDK installed or their path variables weren't correct. However, I have the right version of JDK installed and I have both my PATH and JAVA_HOME variables set.

PATH: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_271\bin`

JAVA_HOME: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_271`

I have JDK installed in the following location:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_271
```

It appears to me that the PATH and JAVA_HOME variables are set correctly. Does anyone know what may be causing this error?

Comment: You'll like need to target the `\bin` subdirectory for both. Does it work if you set `JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_271\bin`? If not, I'll look at my set up and see how it varies.

Comment: Nope, I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: And do you have those variables set as user variables, or system variables? (top or bottom box in Environment Variables window)
For reference, I have my Android and Java paths as user variables.
`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221`,
`C:\Gradle\gradle-5.6.1\bin`,
`C:\Gradle\gradle-5.6.1`,
`C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools`, and
`C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools`
(Granted you'll only need one or two of these)
As system variables I just have `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath`.

Comment: It's occurring to me now that I have all of these as `PATH` and none as `JAVA_HOME`. Looking at the docs for Windows setup with Ionic Cordova, you shouldn't need `JAVA_HOME`.